# "Whip" falling through handle. Collision + Soft Body

Tags: collision, soft-body

I have a four bezier Circle tied to a path that twists to form a rope and a separate object of the handle. The rope runs in the middle of it. I've changed ball weight etc and added the handle as a collision, while the path is a soft body with goal turned off. It seems to hold except for it clips near the very front of the handle.

[image]

Comment: I could upload the blender file I guess if that'd help?

Answer (score 0):

I am totally new to Blender, and I am following this Tutorial where they recommend 'extruding bones' through the Tail (or whip).

Maybe adding an additional 'bone' into the Hilt of the Handle of the whip will allow you to link it to the 'Hand' as a 'Parent-Child' to prevent the Whip Handle from falling away from the Hand.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy6DHSEl5Cs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).